# Load assets in Rails 3.2 with Modernizr.load

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-3

I want to be able to load in certain JS files using Modernizr.load --

```
 Modernizr.load({
  test : Modernizr.touch,
  yep  : '/assets/mobile.js',
  nope : '/assets/desktop.js',
});
```

but when this get compiled for production, those paths do not exist anymore. How can I sort out loading in this way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to add those assets to `config.assets.precompile` in your environment config file (found in config/environments/production.rb). Here's an example:

```
config.assets.precompile += %w(mobile.js desktop.js)
```

These assets can then be referenced by Modernizr:

```
Modernizr.load({
  test : Modernizr.touch,
  yep  : '/assets/mobile.js',
  nope : '/assets/desktop.js',
});
```

EDIT: You should also make sure these assets are **NOT** included in your application.js manifest. Including them in application.js would defeat the purpose of conditionally loading them for specific feature-less browsers.